# IBM Bluemix API for Japanese to English Translation

Tags: ibm-cloud, language-translation

Does IBM Bluemix Watson_developer_cloud API supports Japanese to English translation? 
I am trying to convert Japanese sentence to English using python sample example code provided in watson_developer_cloud examples but I am getting "?????????" as output. There are three domains - conversational, news & patent. Even in Language Translation demo for IBM Bluemix it only shows support for news.

```
text = ('は自動注入ですので').encode('utf-8')
print(json.dumps(language_translator.translate(text, source='ja',target='en'), indent=2,ensure_ascii=False))
```

If I am using:

```
print(json.dumps(language_translator.translate(text,model_id='ja-en-conversational'),indent=2))
```

I am getting model_id not found error. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation it seems that only `News` is supported at this time:

- [Release Notes mention the addition of English to/from Japanese](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/language-translator/release-notes.html) for News category.
- Japanese is not yet listed in the [fully supported languages](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/language-translator/index.html#supported-languages).

I suggest asking in the [Watson Developer slack](http://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/) where the development team is around.